# Azure Batch Pool BlobDownloadMiscError

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a Powershell Script that requires to install modules. These are the **Import-Excel** and **SqlServer** modules. So I've created a Batch Account and Pools with Nodes where I can run the script I've created.

I've uploaded the ps1 file in my storage account, and as for the Modules required I've manually Install the modules in my PC and get the actual files in **/Program Files/WindowsPowerShell/Modules**.

Since these folders have a lot of files inside of it, I've compressed them into a **ZIP file** then **uploaded those in my Storage Account**.

Now in the **Start Task** menu of the Pool I've created, I added the **ZIP files in the Resource Files**.

[image]

Since I need to restart the node in any changes I've made in the Pool after that the **Status of my Node is StartTaskFailed** and here are the errors.

[image]

Is this a FireWall issue? Or do I need to generate a key for the URL or use SAS or Connection strings etc.?

Before doing this approach I've tried doing this approach
[Application Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-application-packages) but It cannot find the file I've specified or trying to Install.

Answer (score 0):

> BlobDownloadMiscError, Status=409 Message=“Public access is not permitted on this storage account.

The above error occurs when you are fetching the file from the storage account without **`SAS token`** or check the storage account may in allowed **`virtual network and firewalls.`**

**Portal:**

While fetching the files from storage check the include **`SAS-token`**  like below:

[image]

Alter change the access level to container level it will act like public access level if you don't want to use SAS-token.

**Portal:**

[image]

Also, check the networking tab if the firewall and virtual
networks are enabled like below.

**Portal:**

[image]

If the firewall and virtual network are enabled follow this [**MS-Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal) to configure.

**Reference:**

[Public access is not permitted on this storage account - Microsoft Community Hub](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/public-access-is-not-permitted-on-this-storage-account/ba-p/3521288)